# Nested if else in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, conditional-statements

Is there any way to implement nested if else functionality in twig? I have tried the following but it isn't working:

```
<body 
        {% if page|default('login') == 'login' %} 
              class="login"
        {% else if( page == 'other') %}
              class="login"
        {% else %}
              class="noclass"
        {% endif %}>
</body>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`elseif` needs to be single word tag/keyword and expression shouldn't have parenthesis same as `if` expression.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html

```
<body
    {% if page|default('login') == 'login' %}
          class="login"
    {% elseif page == 'other' %}
          class="login"
    {% else %}
          class="noclass"
    {% endif %}>
</body>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can aswell use the [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) to shorten your statement...

... and you probably shouldn't repeat the `class=".."` part.

```
<body class="{{ page|default('login') in ['other','login'] ? 'login' : 'noclass' }}">
```